# WPF How to create a grid that can scroll with static column and row header

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created a custom grid with a column and row header. The cells in the grid are empty. What I am trying to do is to create an excel like behavior for it in regards to scrolling. I need to add a horizontal and vertical scrollbar. When you scroll vertically I need the column header to stay in place and the row header to scroll. When you scroll horizontally I need the row column to stay in place and the column header to scroll. Here is the code I currently have for the grid:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas_blueprint" ClipToBounds="True" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=canvas}">
            <DockPanel>
                <Grid x:Name="grid_column_header" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas}"></Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="grid_row_header" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="25" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=canvas}" Margin="0,-25,0,0"></Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="grid_blueprint" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image_blueprint}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image_blueprint}">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="imagebrush_blueprint"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Canvas>
```

Basically it is a canvas with a dockpanel that contains 3 grids. 2 grids for the headers and 1 grid for the inside cells. The cells are created dynamically.

I am making a custom grid because I need to have a background image overlayed on the grid. I tried to use free spreadsheet controls, but have not found one that can have a background image. The only other behavior that my grid needs to have is the ability to select a cell, or a range of cells.

I have tried scrollbars and scrollviewers with the grid, but that makes the lines wonky and uneven. I'm not new to WPF programming, but I am nowhere close to expert. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can our answer involve getting rid of the canvas, or are you using it for something specific that isn't in the code you provided?

Comment: Sure you can get rid of the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a simple `DataGrid`.  It already freezes headers automatically, and you can freeze columns via the `FrozenColumnCount` property.

You can have a background image by setting the `Background` property to an `ImageBrush`.

Selecting ranges can be controlled by setting `SelectionMode` to `DataGridSelectionMode.Extended`.

Here is how you would apply a special background color, and other types of formatting, to individual cells:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpf:DataGridCell}">  
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SomeColorProperty, Converter={StaticResource cellBackgroundConverter}}" />   
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding SomeWeightProperty, Converter={StaticResource cellWeightConverter}}" /> 
        .....
    </Style> 
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: If I use a datagrid in that way, can I just have empty cells like in excel. Basically I want the gridlines, but I want to be able to select a single 'cell' to be able to add a cutomized style to that 'cell'. I also need the ability to highlight a selection of cells.

Comment: Selection can be done that way, but formatting individual cells like that can get tricky.  What kind format variations are you expecting to have?  Are you using the MVVM pattern for this application?

Comment: I'm only familiar with how this would work using MVVM, I've never tried to do it in code-behind.  The basic idea is to set a `CellStyle` on the grid, with a `Setter` to set the specific property (background, font style, font-weight, etc), and a value that is bound to a property on the view model of the cell.  A `ValueConverter` will probably be needed.

Comment: Yes I am using MVVM pattern. The variations would be borders could be either black or red. The format has a bunch of information that would need to be in there. Basically it would have a couple of numbers and a text. That is why I was going for a custom grid so I could customize the cells with a simple grid layout in each cell. This is the only problem I am stuck on right now. I am not sure datagrid would work. I did look into that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some formatting example code. I would recommend you try this in a test project first, so you don't mess up your, mostly working, existing code.  The DataGrid isn't exactly designed to do this, so it may need to be beaten in to shape a little bit, but I still think it is the control that best fits your needs.